# Check if string exists in union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

If I have the following type:

```
type foo = 'bar' | 'baz';
const test = 'bit';
```

How do I check if `test` is a member of `foo`?

(is it really so crazy hard to do as this: [UnionToTuple](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-707364842))

Comment: You can use as `enum` instead and check if test is in the enum. `type` is not emitted in the actual code so you can't really check it at runtime.

Comment: Yea,  unfortunately this is a derived type, so I can't use `as const` definition either

Comment: if your code was `const test : foo = 'bit';` then it would error because `bit` is not of type `foo` is that what you mean or do you mean runtime checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check if a value matches a type alias. Types are erased at runtime, so any runtime code can't ever depend on them.

If you control the type alias I would recommend creating an array to hold the values, let TS infer the type for it, and derive the union from it. You can then check if a value is in the array:

```
const Name = ["Jane", "John"] as const
export type Name = typeof Name[number];

function isName(a: unknown): a is Name {
    return Name.indexOf(a as Name) != -1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was doing, but I don't have control. over the original union, so it was duplicating and separating the type from its source (e.g. graphQL)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use function for validation:

```js
type Foo = 'bar' | 'baz';
const test = 'bit';

const isFoo=(a:Foo)=>a
isFoo(test) // error
isFoo('bar') // ok
```

Comment: This seems close, is there a way to dynamically emit a boolean from `isFoo` based on the argument?

Comment: if argument is not `Foo` you will get compilation error

Comment: yea,  but I simply want to check if the argument  is of that type, then perform actions based on that logic

Comment: Please keep in mind, that during the compilation all types are erased, so I believe you should stick with Louis Weng's solution